# ant cannot find android sdk, ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, netbeans, ant, build.xml

I used to do android development using Netbeans in Fedora 17, I wanted to move to Ubuntu. So I zipped my project, installed Ubuntu 12.04.4, jdk7u51, android sdk, netbeans 7.4, 
the problem is: when I am trying to compile my unzipped project:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**/home/vitali/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:471:** The following error occurred while executing this line:

**/home/vitali/Documents/android projects/ProjectName/build.xml:90:** Cannot find **/home/*vitali/development/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml*** imported from ***/home/vitali/Documents/android projects/ProjectName/build.xml***

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

where: 
/home/vitali/Documents/android projects/ProjectName
is path to the project now in Ubuntu

/home/vitali/development/android-sdk-linux
is the old path which was in Fedora to android-sdk

/home/vitali/Documents/android-sdk-linux
is the new one in Ubuntu

Can anybody tell me why ant is looking android sdk using the old path and how to fix it?

Each time I go in NetBeans tools/sdk manager it asks me to locate android sdk, I do this, then when I reopen NetBeans it happens again, so it doesn't save the path to sdk.

in NetBeans file local.properties has the right path to sdk, but is ignored (I don't know how to fix it).

I created env. variable ANDROID_HOME with path to sdk (export ANDROID_HOME=/home/vitali/Documents/android-sdk-linux) 
but after rebooting computer this variable disappears.

my PATH env. variable:

PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:**/home/vitali/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/vitali/Documents/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools**

Has anyone had this problem before?

update (android update project -p path) doesn't help.

thank you.

**P.S. 
when I create a new project everything is fine, it builds without problems**

Comment: *"Each time I go in NetBeans tools/sdk manager it asks me to locate android sdk*" Looks like you lack permissions to write the configuration file that stores the SDK path.

Comment: probably you are right, if I zipped project in Fedora and unzipped in Ubuntu it should have permissions of Fedora's user, but.. it was me and the user name in both OS is vitali... do you know how can find the config. file that stores the SDK path?

Comment: Just change the owner of the whole folder to avoid further problems: `chown -fR yourUser folder`.

Comment: I tried chown - it didn't help. and I checked the permissions by command ls -n that shows the owner's uid - it is the same as for others files, so the issue is not the wrong owner.

Comment: what is the most interesting thing for me: where is the old path stored?

Comment: I have no idea about NetBeans, sorry.